# Find all records in a table based on other field than ID in springboot using JPA(Conditional Search)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot and making a question answer system. I want to find all questions based on their course id (Which is not a primary key). I am getting an error as: "*query did not return a unique result: 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2*". I am This is my work as of now.

Bean Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="question_id")
    private int question_id;

    @Column(name="question")
    private String question;

    @Column(name="course_id")
    private int courseId;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository("questionRepository")
public interface QuestionRepository extends CrudRepository<Question, Integer>{
    Question findAllByCourseId(int courseId);
}
```

Service:

```
public interface QuestionService {
    Question save(Question question);
    List<Question> listAllQuestion();
    Question findByQuestionName(String questionName);
    List<Question> findAllByCourseId(int courseId);
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
public List<Question> findAllByCourseId(int courseId) {
    return (List<Question>) questionsRepository.findAllByCourseId(courseId);
}
```

I know the code is imperfect in many ways as i am beginner. I want some suggestions too for improvement. Thank you.

Comment: Read your method: it's supposed to find **all** the question**s** by course ID, but its return type is `Question`. It should be `List<Question>`. Also, you really need to learn about the fundamental principles of JPA: there should be an **association** between Question and Course. You shouldn't have a courseId in Question, but a Course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your repository find to list, because you have multiple questions with the same course id.

```
List<Question> findAllByCourseId(int courseId);
```

Comment: This Worked. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

As courseId is not primary key so course contains many courses belong to one CourseId.

So make sure if you are retrieving many records then use List as a return type.

1) In your questionRepository.Make below change.

```
List<Question> findAllByCourseId(int courseId);
```